# selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver wherein I want to get list of all the text present in the table i am able to extract names of all table present in it however i want to extract the names only till specific person i.e "C. Kelly" however my code is extracting all the names below is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='No, thanks!']").click() 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Table')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Table Sort & Search')]").click()
time.sleep(10)
FullName = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@class='sorting_1']")
time.sleep(10)
for Names in FullName:
    if Names == "C. kelly":
            break
    Names1 = Names.text
    print(Names1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a webelement with a string in line `if Names == "C. kelly"`.
You can use `if Names.text == "C. kelly"`.
Also the name in website is *C. Kelly* not *C. kelly*